# Linking error -lplanning_models not found while building rgbslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was presented with the following linking error -lplanning_models not found while building rgbslam. Does anyone know which package this lib belongs to or which package is depending on this lib?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78356/linking-error--lplanning_models-not-found-while-building-rgbslam/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

planning_models seems to be in the arm_navigation stack. It is unclear to me where this dependency should come from. Please don't use hashes (#) for the tags.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0